# Using fscanf to set a variable in a different class

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to read a number from a file and set it to a **public** variable in a different class. The function that is reading the file has a pointer-object instance of that class. I'm facing a weird issue:

The following works:

```
int dummy;
fscanf(file,"%d",&dummy); // assume the file stores the number 10

globals->var = dummy;

cout << "variable is " << globals->var << endl; // this outputs 10 to console. great!
```

But I'm going to have a lot of `fscanf`'s to do, and I don't want to create all of these redundant `dummy` variables. I tried the following:

```
fscanf(file,"%d",&globals->var);
cout << "variable is " << globals->var << endl; // this outputs 2.9e-321 (aka junk)
```

Is there a reason that doesn't work? Do I need to do it like `globals->&var`, or some variation like that? I tried to wrap it in parentheses like so: `&(globals->var)`, but that didn't work either. Is there a reason this is not working (without me having to paste many many many lines of code)

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if I'm doing anything "illegal" in a C++ sort of way...

Comment: what type does globals->var have?

Comment: What is the type of `var`? Post the definition of the class.

Comment: DAMNIT. It has a `double` type. maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in the comment, the type of `var` is double. Yes, that is the problem. You should use `%f` for it.

Apart from that, I would give you a piece of advice:

Prefer using C++ stream for I/O work. They're type-safe. If you use them, you would not face this problem which you faced it with `fprintf`.

Here is how you should use it:

```
std::ifstream file("filename.txt");
file >> globals->var; //don't worry about whether var is int, or double!
```

Cool, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot :) Check will come as soon as the 10 minutes are up

Comment: I know the c++ stream way of reading files. Though it gets a bit annoying when you have to read large chunks of data from a file, whereas it's easier to declare type in the good ol' standard C way using `fscanf`. But I agree, I'd usually go to c++ streams to do this

Comment: @Amit: Why is it annoying to read large files using C++ streams?

Comment: I guess I'm just not that good with them. Usually I like to read a couple numbers from a line, and then use `fgets` to "read" the rest of the line so I don't need to mess around with parameters. to the best of my knowledge, you can't use `fgets` with c++ streams, and you can't tell them to "skip the rest of the content and go to the next line"

Comment: @Nawaz: It is mondo annoying. C++ I/O is much more verbose than C, is just as error-prone as C I/O but in a different way, and is incredibly fragile. C++ I/O is one of the features of C++ I dislike the most. That said, `fscanf` is not the way to go. Read into a buffer and scan (somehow). Now C++ does add advantages over C. It provide some very nice parsing tools, ranging from simple `std::string` methods all the way up to regexes.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is most probably that globals->var is a `float` or `double` convert it to an `int` or some other integer-type and it should work

The reason why it's outputting "junk" is that `float`/`double` numbers are encoded in a special way. If you just overwrite that memory with an perfectly valid integer like:

```
double value = 0.0;
*((int*)&value) = 42;
// value is now something like 2.07508e-322
```

you nonetheless get a "strange" number. This is what happens internally in scanf with %d as parameter.

Comment: Actually, it invokes undefined bevahiour, if you mismatch the type and the format-specifier.

Comment: And even a halfway decent compiler should tell you that you have done so -- if you turn on warnings, that is. Mismatching type and format specifier is just one of many undefined behaviors that most compilers will catch if you ask them to do so. Fail to ask and all kinds of bad behaviors will slip through unreported.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I had -Wall turned on, as well as a bunch of other -W compiler flags. The compiled without any warnings at all. Weird.

Comment: @Amit: What compiler? With multiple compilers, no warnings enabled whatsoever, I get warnings along the lines of `warning: format '%d' expects type 'int*', but argument 3 has type 'double*'` for `fscanf (stdin, "%d", &double_variable);`

Comment: @DavidHammen: I used the intel `icpc` compiler with the following compile flags: `CXXFLAGS = -O3 -I.. -Wall -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings`